# In SQL how to do a Count Same values in a column SQL with 5 more columns not in GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I I have 5 columns in select list and want to add one more counting column which counts the number of same [Locations] for each [Locations] in that column. Below is my code:

```
SELECT [ItemTable].[Item_Number],
       [ProductTable].[Product Series],
       [SalesTable].[Locations],
       COUNT(SalesTable.Locations),
       [ItemTable].[Quantity],
       [SalesTable].[Shipping Date]
FROM [ItemTable] 
  inner join [SalesTable] on 
  [ItemTable].[Sales_Doc_Num]=[SalesTable].[Sales_Doc_Num] 
  left join [ProductTable] on
  [ItemTable].[Item_Number]=[ProductTable].[ITEMNMBR]
WHERE[SalesTable].[Shipping Date]='04/03/2020'
GROUP BY SalesTable.Locations
```

The error is:

> Column 'Item_Number' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I know this is a logic error but I don't know how to deal with this case. I tried to add all those columns into GROUP BY clause, there wouldn't be any error but all values in counting column is 1, which is not what I'm looking for.
I've also tried subqueries but ran into another error.

The final data I'm looking for is like:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean keep the counting column with 1s and sum them up for each Location? what is it about with Shipping date?

Comment: Then change your logic.  You count first, then join with the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a window count rather than aggregation:

```
SELECT [ItemTable].[Item_Number],
       [ProductTable].[Product Series],
       [SalesTable].[Locations],
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY SalesTable.Locations) CNT,  --> here
       [ItemTable].[Quantity],
       [SalesTable].[Shipping Date]
FROM [ItemTable] 
  inner join [SalesTable] on 
  [ItemTable].[Sales_Doc_Num]=[SalesTable].[Sales_Doc_Num] 
  left join [ProductTable] on
  [ItemTable].[Item_Number]=[ProductTable].[ITEMNMBR]
WHERE[SalesTable].[Shipping Date]='04/03/2020'
```